# Mock up SharePoint Rest API using NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sharepoint

I'm trying to create a development environment for a small sharepoint application.  The application queries a couple of Sharepoint 2013 lists and builds a custom view of the data.  Rather than publishing to sharepoint every time I make a change I would like to use NodeJS and Express 4 to mock up the api.  I don't need to mock up any of other CRUD activities; just the GET requests.

I started out using the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const csv = require('csvtojson');

const app = express();
function openAndSend(file, res){
  csv().fromFile(path.join(__dirname,file))
  .then(jsonarray)=>{
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
    res.send({d:{results:jsonarray}});
  });
}

app.get('/dataset',(req,res)=>{
  openAndSend('./data/dataset.csv', res);
});

app.get('/people',(req,res)=>{
  openAndSet('./data/people.csv', res);
});
```

How can I use express js to mock up something like 
`/api/lists/getbytitle("Data Set")/items` and `/api/lists/getbytitle("People")/items`

I tried changing the `app.get` functions to `app.get('/api/lists/getbytitle("Data%20Set")/items', ....);` which did not work.  However removing get `getbytitle("`...`")"` routed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue using express Router and a regex expression for the path/route.  The most challenging part was discovering that special characters needed to be encoded.

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get(/getbytitle\((%22|')Data%20Set(%22|')\)\/items\/?$/i,(req,res,next)=>{
   openAndSend('./data/dataset.csv', res);
});

router.get(/getbytitle\((%22|')people(%22|')\)\/items\/?$/i,(req,res,next)=>{
   openAndSend('./data/people.csv', res);
});
app.use('/_api/lists',router);
```